# SQL Server - How to prevent sql server from disconnect the idle connection after period of time?

Tags: sql-server

i am using sql server 2012 with desktop application as client , the application get errors after period of time when no activity on it , i googled about this issue all solutions points  me to **AUTO_CLOSE** option on database but it's already set to false .

i thing is something missing in connection string (ADO Extension)

Comment: The good practice is to get the connection from pool for a short period, do activity and then put the connection back to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if you have long running connections, you can hit these errors regardless due to firewalls / routers closing connections, etc. The correct solution is to instantiate a connection when you need it, use the connection and release it. With connection pooling, this is not really a performance problem.

If your long-running application is "bursty", it is sometimes convenient to open the connection, do a number of commands -- then when you go idle, release the connection and wait the next burst of activity.

Comment: Agreed. Basically, every time you need database access open a new Connection, use it, then Close it. Connection Pooling works in the background and will automatically re-use the connections when appropriate.